# The back button in a navigation bar is shown in ios7/ios8 but not in ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

The device runs ios8 and the back button is properly shown and I can use a swipe gesture on the device to navigate the view stack.

On the simulator (running ios9), the back button will not appear, and the swipe gesture does not work.

UPDATE: I have updated the device to use ios9, the back button vanished.

Comment: Please provide more context (eg: sample code showing the problem).

Comment: it is in a storyboard, there is no code manipulating the navbar. what code are you interested in? I cannot pinpoint the problematic lines...

Comment: i addes code as requested,aybe you see an issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the source for this.

In the storyboard, the navigation controllers were cascaded.

The segue of the first controller stacked another full view controller, not just the view. On that view controller, the navigation was not properly initialized.

On ios7/ios8, this made no difference, the root-navigation controller's navigation bar was used. In ios9, it seems, that the navigation bar of the initial navigation controller is overwritten or it requires specific segues to the parent navigation view.

If the swipe feature is also dependent on the missing navigation bar initialisation, I have not tested. I have removed the superfluous navigation controllers and directed the segues directly to the views and now it works.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What does "the navigation was not properly initialized" mean in this case?mI have the same trouble, and so far no clue how to get my navigation back. Even though the StoryBoard editor shows the navigation, when running the App it's all gone.

Comment: This is some time ago. As written, in the storyboard, one nav controller was forwarding to another full nav controller. If I remember correctly, the navigation bar in the second controller had not been initialized correctly (nil values). When I removed the second nav controller and replaced it with a normal view controller as child, the button came back and the navigation worked as expected (and as in ios7)